# Mint From Existing Contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, abi

I have the following contract that is already deployed (pasted below). I can see where the `constructor()` method is doing an `emit Transfer` from the 0x0 (zero) address to the deployer address in order to mint the initial supply, but how would I use `emit Transfer` in another function to distribute tokens via mint OR how would I use the `transferFrom()` to mint new tokens with the same contract to the deployer address?

Couldn't I just do `transferFrom(0x0, msg.sender, SUPPLY_AMOUNT)`? Trying this, but keep getting an error.

I'm familiar with Remix, so if there's a way to do it there, I can probably get it.

Here's the contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

library SafeMath {

  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    // uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return a / b;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
    c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  uint256 totalSupply_;

  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender)
    public view returns (uint256);

  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value)
    public returns (bool);

  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(
    address indexed owner,
    address indexed spender,
    uint256 value
  );
}

contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;

  function transferFrom(
    address _from,
    address _to,
    uint256 _value
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function allowance(
    address _owner,
    address _spender
   )
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
  {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  function increaseApproval(
    address _spender,
    uint _addedValue
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = (
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue));
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval(
    address _spender,
    uint _subtractedValue
  )
    public
    returns (bool)
  {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

contract MYTOKEN is StandardToken {

  string public constant name = "MYTOKEN"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  string public constant symbol = "MYTOKEN"; // solium-disable-line uppercase
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18; // solium-disable-line uppercase

  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 100000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

  constructor() public {
    totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
emit Transfer(0x0, msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
```

is emitting and event `Transfer`, its content does not have any effect on the blockchain. It only uses as a notification mechanism to off-chain code (for example, a webapp listening to this to show user about the event).

The only 2 ways you can mint token are:

1. Via the `_mint` function if that can be accessed by a public function and the token implements it (mintable) [ERC20 Openzeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC20)
2. Change the `balances[addr]` and  `totalSupply_` directly (which is what happens in the above constructor).

Because you cannot call the `constructor` of deployed contract and there are no ways to achieve any of the above methods, the answer to your question is **it's not possible**. You must implement a new token or deploy a new instance of the contract to receive the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Like minhhn2910 said , since you don't have a *public* or *external* `mint` function, you cannot create more tokens. Your `INITIAL_SUPPLY` is your maximum and final `totalSupply_` (since you cannot burn nor send to the 0 address neither).

The only thing you can do is ***manually distribute tokens*** from the **deployer** address, or have the deployer address **allow an other address** to distribute its tokens on its behalf.

On top of that there are quite a lot of things to say about this contract:

- Some bad practices (constant variables are CAPITAL_CASE, ERC20 metada shouldn't be hardcoded but given as constructor input ...)
- missing IERC165 and IERC20...
- When using versions greater than 0.8 you don't need SafeMaths library since overflow and underflow checks are integrated.
- Over splitting functionalities in contracts isn't recommended and
- Contracts that define function headers but don't implement them are generally defined as Interfaces.